# How do I bind to Android service that is started after boot completed?

Tags: android, service

I have an Android app with a Service, and an Activity_A and an Activity_B.

The service has to start after boot completed (which is does). When I launch the app, the service has to bind to Activity_A. When Activity_B is launched, it has to unbind from Activity_A and bind to Activity_B. The Service must never be destroyed since boot completed. That's all I need.

I tried two methods of binding to the server and both had problems:

- Method 1:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
  bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  ```

  This destroys the Service when it binds from Activity_A to Activity_B.
- Method 2:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
  startService(intent);
  bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  ```

  This seems to create a new service when Activity_A is launched. (But it should bind to the Service that has been created after boot completed)

Do you have any tips how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so Method 2 works totally fine. I figured that another problem occured that caused trouble. So I successfully use Method 2 now!